# Subquery to return multiple columns from newest record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, multiple-columns

I got a table structure like this:

**Document**

```
ID  | NAME  | DATA
----+-------+--------
1   | Doc1  | Data1
2   | Doc2  | Data2
```

**History**:

```
HID | DOC_ID    | HDATA1    | HDATA2    | HDATA3
----+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------
1   | 1         | A         | B         | C
2   | 2         | C         | D         | E
3   | 1         | A         | A         | B
4   | 1         | B         | B         | D
5   | 2         | E         | A         | C
```

The output I like to get is the fields `NAME`,`DATA` and `HDATA1`,`HDATA2` and `HDATA3` values from the newest record in `HISTORY` (highest HID) that matches the corresponding ID from the `Documents` table.

The examples I have found only returns one value from one column, but I need data from several columns. I can't figure how to set up this SQL.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly share your desired output.

Comment: Updated question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Example works for Oracle and might be adapted slightly for different SQL dialects:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ( SELECT h.*,
                d.*,
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY h.DOC_ID ORDER BY h.HID DESC) AS RNK
           FROM History h
           JOIN Document d ON d.ID = h.DOC_ID )
 WHERE RNK = 1
```

Tested with following data:

```
INSERT INTO Document VALUES ( 1   , 'Doc1'  , 'Data1' );
INSERT INTO Document VALUES ( 2   , 'Doc2'  , 'Data2' );

INSERT INTO History VALUES ( 1   , 1         , 'A'         , 'B'         , 'C' );
INSERT INTO History VALUES ( 2   , 2         , 'C'         , 'D'         , 'E' );
INSERT INTO History VALUES ( 3   , 1         , 'A'         , 'A'         , 'B' );
INSERT INTO History VALUES ( 4   , 1         , 'B'         , 'B'         , 'D' );
INSERT INTO History VALUES ( 5   , 2         , 'E'         , 'A'         , 'C' );
```

Result:

```
HID     DOC_ID HDATA1     HDATA2     HDATA3             ID NAME       DATA              RNK
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         4          1 B          B          D                   1 Doc1       Data1               1 
         5          2 E          A          C                   2 Doc2       Data2               1
```

Comment: @Lars -You don't need a subquery for this. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Document d
inner join (
            select h1.* from  History h1
            inner join (
                         select max(hid) as hid from History group by doc_id 
                        ) h2
            on h1.hid = h2.hid
           ) t
on t.doc_id = d.doc_id
```

Comment: Thanks jophab. I just tried this and the values from the history table is not included in the result

Answer (score 0):

The below query would return the newest record for each Document ID

```
   SELECT 
            ID, Name, DATA, HDATA1, HDATA2, HDATA3 
   FROM Document D CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 HDATA1, HDATA2, HDATA3 FROM History H WHERE D.ID=H.DOC_ID ORDER BY H.HID DESC) A
```

Query cost would be relatively low by using cross apply in this scenario..
It could show up the best results in query estimated execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much elegant way to achieve this using window function `row_number` in the ordering clause in conjunction with `TOP 1 with ties`. No Subquery needed.

```
select top 1 with ties *
from document d
join history h
    d.id = h.doc_id
order by row_number() over (
            partition by d.id
            order by h.hid desc
            );
```

It returns one record per document with latest History ID.